# How to get current product category ID in product archive page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

If I am on a product archive page then how can I get current product category ID in product archive page. I am using this but no result:

```
global $wp_query;
$category_name = $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'];
$category_object = get_term_by('name', $category_name, 'product_cat');
$category_id = $category_object->term_id;
```

Answer (score 26):

I solve This To get the current category ID.

```
$cate = get_queried_object();
$cateID = $cate->term_id;
echo $cateID;
```

and it works like a charm.

Comment: it gives this error: Notice: Undefined property: WP_Post_Type::$term_id in file.php

Comment: @Exclutips Nice! Got the job done for me! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Funciona perfeitamente!

```
    <?php
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
    if( $term = get_term_by( 'id', $product_cat_id, 'product_cat' ) ){echo $term->name;}
    break;
}?>
```