# Can't get taxonomy ID for each post on archive page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, terms

I'm trying to get an individual posts custom taxonomy ID to then print an image with ACF. I've looked at the [documentation here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/) on ACF and this [support ticket too](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get-value-from-taxonomy-term/).

From my understanding it looks like it should work if if I use `get_queried_object()`, however I'm not having much luck.

Here is my code:

```
<?php $producers_assessment_object = get_queried_object();?>
<?php the_field('badge', 'producers_assessment_' . $producers_assessment_object->term_id); ?>
```

If I manually put in the post ID like so `<?php the_field('badge', 'producers_assessment_7'); ?>` the field works as I would like it to.

I've tried using this code below from a[nother SO questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198422/how-to-get-current-product-category-id-in-product-archive-page), just to see if I can the term Id in anyway and this also didn't work.

```
$cate = get_queried_object();
$cateID = $cate->term_id;
echo $cateID;
```

Here is the code from my functions.php for my custom taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy(  
        'producers_assessment',  //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces). 
        'producers',        //post type name
        array(  
            'hierarchical' => true,  
            'label' => 'Assessment Stage',  //Display name
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'producer-assessment', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                'with_front' => false // Don't display the category base before 
            )
        )  
    );
```

Comment: I think maybe you're confusing the global queried object present on a term archive page with the individual terms assigned to each post. Is this a taxonomy term archive page? That's the only case where the term data would be the queried object. You say *each post* so it sounds like you want something like `get_the_terms` instead to fetch the terms assigned to each post.

Comment: I haven't used ACF in a long while but `term_id` is not a property of the post object.  Take a look at `get_the_terms()` instead.

Comment: Ha, or what Milo just said!  Always listen to Milo.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at get_the_terms. I've updated my question to include my custom taxonomy code if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From the help of the comments above I needed to use get_term_terms to print the ID.

I used the code below to achieve what I needed:

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'producers_assessment' ); 
        foreach($terms as $term) {?>
            <?php 
            $image = get_field('badge', 'producers_assessment_' . $term->term_id);
            if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" width="50" height="50" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php } ?>
```